# Efficient implementation of seperable convolution in tensorflow

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolution, faster-rcnn

It seems like the native implementation of separable convolution in tensorflow is not efficient.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12940

Is anyone aware how can we get an efficient implementation of separable convolution in tensorflow from somewhere?

If not is there any working/efficient implementation of separable convolution in other libraries?